# How to integrate Twistlock with AWS Fargate using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

We are using AWS Fargate tasks to run our containers and as part of securing these containers we wanted to add twistlock to scan these images and help us secure the app images. I have some knowledge on what twistlock does, but not sure how it needs to be integrated with the Fargate tasks and how it communicates with the other app images. We use CDK to manage our infra, so it would be helpful if someone has done this and/or are aware of this implementation to integrate twistlock with AWS fargate using CDK or otherwise can help with the inputs. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you add this twist lock scanning functionality in the CI/CD pipeline?

the flow would be you check-in the code, run twistlock job as a job, and then run a script of cdk deploy and twist lock is available as docker image too.

Comment: "run twistlock job as a job", do we have any pointers on how we can run this job to fetch an image, ideally I was looking for how can the application image before it does it job, ideally the entry point would be to first install the twistlock and then the container would be available up to service the requests.

Comment: You absolutely do **not** want to run Twistlock inside the docker image that it is scanning. As mentioned above, this is a task that should be performed in a CI/CD environment before the image is ever deployed to ECS.